# Loop over part of Matrix

Tags: for-loop, matrix, indexing, octave

I have a Matrix A. I want to iterate over the inner part of the matrix (B), while also working with the rows and columns that are not part of B.

```
A = [1 4 5 6 7 1;    B = [2 2 2 2;
     8 2 2 2 2 1;         2 3 3 2;
     9 2 3 3 2 1;         2 8 2 2];
     0 2 8 2 2 1;      
     1 1 1 1 1 1];
```

I know it is possible to select the part of A like this:

```
[rows,columns] = size(A);
B = A([2:1:rows-1],[2:1:columns-1]);
for i = 1:(rows*columns)
    %do loop stuff
endfor
```

This however wont work because I also need the outer rows and columns for my calculations. How can I achieve a loop without altering A?

Comment: I want to loop through matrix A, but only through the values in B. I know how to separate A from B but that is not enough, because I also want to use the values missing from B. For example: A(7) = A(7)+(2)

Comment: I want to do calculations realative to every i in the loop. If I seperate the two matrices I can't (or don't know how to) do that.

Comment: What are you doing in `%do loop stuff`? It sounds suspiciously like you want to do filtering or convolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, why do not use two indexes for the inner matrix?

```
%....
for i=2:rows-1
    for j=2:cols-1
        % here, A(i,j) are the B elements, but you
        % can still access to A(i-1, j+1) if you want.
    end
end
%....
```